# strip: Формат файла не распознан

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, install

Столкнулся с ошибкой после выполнения команды make install в окружении cygwin при установке библиотеки:

```
install -m 755 -p /dst/include/mylib/writer.h /usr/local/include/mylib/  
strip /usr/local/include/mylib/writer.h  
strip:/usr/local/include/mylib/writer.h: Формат файла не распознан  
make[1]: [Makefile:244: install_copy_lib_headers] Ошибка 1 (игнорирование)
```

Comment: так вам помощь не нужна? если вы уже нашли решение то лучше сначала разместите вопрос, а потом разместите ответ к нему и примите его

Comment: Да, спасибо Михаил

Comment: Вам спасибо за то, что делитесь найденными решениями

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема возникает в файловой системе NTFS и лечится настройкой прав доступа:

```
find /dst/include/mylib/ -iname '*.h' -print0 | xargs -0 chmod -c -x
```

Подробнее, например, [здесь](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/16301-Qt-installation-error).

Comment: на галочку нажмите слева от ответа, чтобы принять его как "правильный"

Comment: только через два дня это станет доступным)

Comment: ok) sorry) на собственные вопросы не отвечал - не знал об этом ограничении